# calling user defined functions in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, video

I am coding a search engine for videos. For every video I have stored some tags(like tutorials, beginners, movies, errors etc.,). Since generally we can extract key words from users query, I have created a database which contain (key word, tag, probability)

eg: If database entry is

```
key word  |   tag  |   probability

how to    | errors |    0.7
```

it means that If a key word "how to" exists in users query, it is 70% probable that user is searching for a video with tag "errors".

Multiple key words can be extracted from user's query. So, i stored them in an array.

In videos database, for every video, I am storing 2 attributes ( video_name , tag , relevance )
relevance states "how relevant the video is with respect to the tag".
A video can have multiple tags. So, if there are 4 tags for a video, there will 4 entries in videos database with different tags and relevances.

Finally, I want an sql query such that, it returns sum of relevance * probability of all tags for a video.
Eg:
If tags extracted are 
movies - 0.6 probability and songs - 0.8 probability

and if videos database is

```
video_name | tag     | relevance

  A        |  movies |   50

  B        |  errors |   100

  A        |  songs  |   100

  C        |  tutorial|  10

  A        |  comedy  |  200
```

then my result have to be 
 A   -  100      ( 50 * 0.6    +   100 * 0.8 )

B   -  0        ( 0 since tag is not found )

C   -  0        ( 0 since tag is not found )

I am new to sql. Can you please give an sql query for this...... Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keywords table is called `keywords` and your relevances table `relevances`, something like this should work:

```
SELECT video_name, sum(r.relevance * k.probablility)
FROM relevances r, keywords k
WHERE r.tag = k.tag
GROUP BY video_name
ORDER BY video_name
```

It should return NULL (not 0) for the videos without tags.